# Is there any code available online for CHA-1?

Tags: hash, reference-request

Is there any code available online for the chaos-based hash algorithm **CHA-1**?

I am trying to apply the methodology of [this paper](http://researchgate.net/publication/253155858) to blockchain applications.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic on CryptoSE. Try asking on [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if you're looking for specific software.

Comment: @AleksanderRas I am sorry for the of-topic question I will delete the question on the afternoon :)

Comment: We worried about whatever process leads you to study this article. No competent person with good intentions towards you would recommend it.

Comment: Ok thank you for the helpful feedback @fgrieu , but since i am interested on studying adaptable hashing ,meaning the way the algorithm is prepossessed is changing on different conditions (which the sensitivity on initial conditions chaos provides) , Do you have any suggestions for that? (maybe i will post similar thread)

Comment: _"adaptable hashing, meaning the way the algorithm is prepossessed is changing on different conditions"_ seems to be what HMAC does. It turns SHA-256 or SHA-512 into hashes parameterized by a key. SHA-3 makes it even simpler (just hash the appropriately padded key before the message).

Answer (score 4):

This is an obscure and not peer-reviewed article of dubious quality (I'm being polite). It has far too many flaws to list here. It should be best left ignored. The author did not publish a reference implementation, and the software they used is most likely just a proof-of-concept, not usable in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I am following the methodology from the following literature : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253155858 and I also trying to a proof-of-concept on adaptive hashing on the blockchain. Sorry for not being more descriptive in my initial question.

Comment: As above, that's not a recommended hash function. Don't use it. *ALL* hash functions involve chaos theory, that's not an interesting feature, more a trivial pre-requisite.

Comment: Ok thank you for the helpful feedback @SAIPeregrinus , just like I commented above I am interested on studying adaptable hashing ,meaning the way the algorithm is prepossessed is changing on different conditions (which the sensitivity on initial conditions chaos provides) , Do you have any suggestions for that? That would be really helpful. (maybe i will post similar thread)

Comment: @econ What you describe as "adaptable/adaptive hashing" does not make sense. Maybe you are looking for keyed hashing algorithms, such as HMAC or SHA-3.

Comment: @A.Hersean: actually, SHA-3 is not keyed.  Might you mean KMAC?

Comment: @poncho You can key SHA-3 by appending or prepending a fixed-length key to the message, making it a MAC. This was a design goal of SHA-3. KMAC provides good default values and enforce the constant length of the key.